# How to marshall large java objects to xml without heap error?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling

Currently I am using JAXB marshaller to marshall the large java object and it is working but when i recive the large java object application is throwing the OutOfMemoryError: heap space error.

Can some one let me know how to marshall large java object to xml without heap error.

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
JAXBContext.newInstance("packageName").createMarshaller.marshall(myObject,writer);
return writer.toString();
```

Here is the exact stack error,

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.ensureCapacityImpl(StringBuffer.java:338)
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:114)
    at java.io.StringWriter.write(StringWriter.java:88)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.flushBuffer(BufferedWriter.java:122)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(BufferedWriter.java:246)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.cleanUp(MarshallerImpl.java:339)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:332)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:249)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.marshal(AbstractMarshallerImpl.java:95)
    at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.jaxb.marshal.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:210)
    at com.mine.app.util.AppUtility.marshalXMLPayload(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: How large your object is?

Comment: Almost 15MB of size.

Comment: try using SAX isntead of DOM

Comment: If the object is large, why do you need its XML representation as a String ? Will a file be more proper destination?

Comment: And how many such objects do you have at time?

Comment: Max of 20 objects at a time.

Comment: @Harry.Chen : That string will be sending in a Queue

Comment: Then I think it's the String objects eat your memory, not the JAXB.

Comment: @reddy1234 Hint: use a profiler to understand what is going on in your JVM. Anything else is mere guessing. When you understand the actual things that consume memory; then you can think about solutions to that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will give you the short and long answer.

### Short (practical) answer

You have 20 objects, 15Mb each one. It means that they occupy ~300Mb. Probably XML representation occupies twice more. So, configure you JVM heap to 1 - 2 G and forget continue your development. (use `-Xmx1G`) command line option when running JVM.

### Longer answer

Why does OOM happens? You serialize object into XML using JAXB that uses DOM. This means that first the system creates DOM representation of your huge object, then it serializes it into textual form. All this requires a lot of memory. 
You can avoid using JAXB and find other tool for serializing object to XML or write your own code. I am not sure, but try XStream. It is very strong tool and is able to use SAXt at least for parsing, so probably it knows to serialize objects incrementally too. 
This solution is more scaleable than the first one but requires coding.

BTW: make sure that when your serializing the object you marshal it directly to file (or web resource or other external target) and not to byte array or string.

## EDIT

Your latest additions to your question proved my fears.
Your problem is not in JAXB serialization but in creating huge string. Why are you doing this? I doubt that you store it in RAM for future use. I believe that you immediately write it to some stream (file, network, whatever - does not matter.) This means that you actually should not create the string at all. Do not use `StringWriter` and then `StringWriter.toString()` (where the exception is thrown). If you want to write XML to file use `FileWriter` directly.

Comment: I have to serialize to String because I have to sent this across MQ, for which I am using spring jms-template.

Comment: Your short answer works but i want to go ahead with out increasing the heap size.

Comment: Ok, so read the longer answer and make your decision. But first please take a look on your code that marshals the object (see the end of my answer marked with BTW).

Comment: JAXB does not convert to DOM first.

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan, could you please explain more?

Comment: JAXB implementations convert directly to a `Writer`, `OutputStream`, `ContentHandler` or StAX output without any sort of DOM representation.  You mention that XStream doesn't do that and neither does JAXB.  In general object-XML libraries don't because it's not necessary and would have poor performance.

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan, thanks for clarification. This means that the last comment from my answer is indeed relevant. reddy1234, check your code that calls marshaller. Do you marshal the the content directly to file or to a kind of buffer?

Comment: @AlexR  My code is marshalling directly to a StringWriter which internwill have buffer i believe.

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan: Can you please let me know if you have any answer for this without increasing the heap size, I am stuck at this heap issue now

Comment: @reddy1234, could you please post code snippet that shows how are you dealing with the marshaller? It is in continuation to the last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: @AlexR, here is the exact classnames with packages, javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext. javax.xml.bind.Marshaller

Comment: I am creating String because I need to send the marshalled data via MQ in String format and am using spring jms-template for this.

Comment: So, re-think your design or increase heap. It is not a good practice to send so huge objects as an JMS message attachment. Alternatively you can store XML in file and send message with file path. BTW if your object is serializable you probably do not have to create XML at all. Other possible solution is to use StreamMessage: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/jms/StreamMessage.html